# Stratified Sampling - Confim usage and sample size

Tags: survey, cluster-sample

I want to conduct a survey on a population of college students to run models on.  My hope is that it will accurately represent the population. I am concerned about the sample not giving a close proportion of students from each college (business, engineering, fine arts, etc). Would it make sense to run a stratified sample here, and if so what would be the best way to calculate the sample sizes?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your sample to be representative of the population in terms of the distribution of college membership, then stratified random sampling is the right tool. To achieve a representative sample, sample sizes should be proportional to the fraction of the population which belongs to each school. So, if 75% of students are in the business school and 25% are in the engineering school, you should sample three times as many business school students as engineering students.

If you want a sample of size $S$ stratified with respect to schools $i=1, 2, \cdots$ that have populations of size $p_i$, you should collect samples of size $s_i$ from school $i$, where

$$s_i = \frac{p_i}{\sum p_i}S$$